# Can't find class - at whits end

Tags: php, class

Long story short, I had some working code, now it doesn't, and I'm very close to thrusting a knife into my trachea because of it.

Simplest thing in PHP I know, including a page which contains a class for later OOP.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once 'backend/shapecollectionclass.php';

//POST name and colour
$name = $_POST["name"];
$colour = $_POST["colour"];
```

/************ SQUARE **************/

```
switch($shapename)
{
case "square":{
$side=$_POST["side"]; 
$sq1 = new Square("Square", $colour, $side);
$shapes->app($sq1);}

?>
```

In the directory the file with the above code exits in is the file backend, which contains the file shapecollectionclass.php, which includes the class Shape from another file, which is extended by Square in another.

* shapecollectionclass.php *************

```
<?phpinclude_once 'shapeclass.php';?>
```

* shapeclass.php ******

```
<?php
abstract class Shape
etc...
?>
```

* squareclass.php ********

```
<?php
class Square extends Shape
etc...?>
```

I know this question isn't in a format that is reasonable/makes sense. I just don't know what to do. The code worked. I cannot recall touching it, now it doesn't, and older versions which definitely were not even modified anywhere do not even work now.

Have to at least give stackoverflow a try before I give up on this assignment, even if I will battle to understand any of the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, so I've made a best guess.

You need to include `squareclass.php` somewhere, most likely in `shapecollectionclass.php`. Currently you're not including `class Square` anywhere so it's not defined, if I understand your question correctly. Your files should look something like this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'backend/shapecollectionclass.php';

// Etc...

$square = new Square(/* ... */);
```

**shapecollectionclass.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'squareclass.php';
```

**shapeclass.php**

```
<?php
abstract class Shape {
    // Etc...
}
```

**squareclass.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'shapeclass.php';

class Square extends Shape {
    // Etc...
}
```

It's unclear what `shapecollectionclass.php` is for, so it might make more sense to include `squareclass.php` in your main file.

It might be a good idea to explore [autoloading](http://php.net/autoload) to mitigate this kind of issues.